# How to create an object with a default template and skip rendering the form in the new view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I have a PagesController that allows a user to create a page with the following data rendering on that page

```
headline
background image
text color
buttontext
button text color
buttoncolor
```

I want to make it so that when a user clicks the new page button it skips the form in the new view and just creates the page with default images, text, etc.

How do I skip the new method / form and just create/save the object in the database?

Comment: Simple, just create the object in your `new` action (same you do in `create`) instead of rendering the new form.

Comment: thanks could you give me an example as your answer. Visual learner:)

Comment: @user3787971 The "example" is in your `create` action already. Just copy it to your `new` action as Sergio said. You'll have to, of course, load attribute data from some other source besides `params` (since there are no `params` to choose from). If you're lucky, someone with plenty of free time will write the code for you like you're asking... but that isn't what SO is for. So it's not coming from me.

Comment: ok thanks giving it a try now will come back with what worked and answer @wesfoster

Comment: @wesfoster I answered it thanks to you both for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2):

Per the comments above I figured it out.

pages_controller.rb

```
def new
    @page = Page.new(default)
    @page.user = current_user 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.save
        format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @page }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def create 
  end
```

Finally, I stored the default variables in a private hash in a default method.

```
private

 def default
      {:headline => "The Wildest Landing Page In The West", :color => "White",  :buttoncolor => "warning", :buttontext => "Button Text", :image => nil, :user_id => current_user}
    end
```

I'm using the paperclip gem so I had to add the default background image in the view like using css and a simple if statement. Not sure if this is the best way to do this but it's working.

```
  <% if @page.image_file_name === nil %>
       <div class="default-bg bg-image">

    <% else %>
        <div class="bg-image" style="background-image: url('<%= @page.image.url %>'); no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover;">
            <h1>no image here</h1>
    <% end %>
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Great job figuring it out as well as formatting your answer! Hopefully this will help others with the same question in the future.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me @WesFoster stoked I got it right and I hope it does help! Really made a big difference for my UX.